# If one of the attributes is present then another should be required else both must be optional

Tags: xml, xsd

Let's say I've following content in XML:

```
<shape type="rectangle" fontSize="14.11" width="10" height="5" />
<shape type="roundedrectangle" fontSize="16" />
<shape type="circle" fontSize="12" />
<shape type="roundedrectangle" fontSize="11" width="10" height="5" />
```

I want to create an XSD which validates if "width" is present as an attribute then "height" must be present in that element and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Must be done in code.

### XSD 1.1

Can be done via an [assertion](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#rf-assertions):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="shape">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:assert test="(@height and @width) or (not(@height) and not(@width))"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks kj hughes. I've to work with XSD 1.0 lets see when we move to XSD 1.1

Comment: kj hughes I've not checked your answer for XSD 1.1 but as per the available information over internet, assertion is the way to solve my query so I am accepting your answer. Thanks.